# How to get information about query plans that are out of cache?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

In SQL Server there are a lot of DMV/Fs and other options which allow me to get information about query plans that are in cache, but I can't find any method to get information about all query plans, not just ones saved in cache. Can you, please, show how can I explore all query plans such as a number of times it has been used, its size, etc.?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean - where else would query plans be stored other than the cache?

Comment: Cache holds plans only for actively used queries, less used queries fall out of cache usually in case of memory shortage @George.Palacios

Comment: You can even manually flush the cache

Comment: Yes so I'm asking where you expect those plans that are flushed to be kept? As far as I'm aware once they're gone, they're gone.

Comment: I'm just asking that. Aren't they saved anywhere? And how is it possible to get info about them?

Comment: @EleonoraGrigoryan, check out [query store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store) if you are using SQL Server 2016+.

Comment: There are also monitoring tools that - among all the other things they provide - store plans over time, regardless of their current cache status, for all supported SQL Server versions, without having to be turned on per database, and without storing all that performance data in each database. [Worth a look](https://www.sentryone.com/products/sentryone-platform/sql-sentry/sql-server-performance-monitoring). *Disclaimer: I work for SentryOne.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dan noted, you can use Query Store on [SQL Server 2016+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017).

If you're on an earlier version, you can try [Open Source Query Store](https://www.openquerystore.com/), though I don't have any experience with using it.

As a last resort, you could log [sp_BlitzCache](http://firstresponderkit.org) to a table. There are instructions on doing that in the README. I'm not going to post them here. Fair warning: I contribute to that open source project.